# How to use where condition in fetch URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I am using third party api in their sdk they have given option to fetch data on the base of where condition like this

```
    Ordering.users.all({
            mode: 'dashboard',
            params: 'id,name,lastname',
            where: [
                {
                    attribute: 'level',
                    value: {
                        condition: '=',
                        value: 4,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },function (res) {
            if (!res.error) {
                $scope.drivers_filter = res.result
            } else MyAlert.show(res.result)
        })
```

in the console it seems like this

```
Request URL: https://apiv4.ordering.co/v400/es-419-1/devyv4/users?mode=dashboard&params=id,name,lastname&where=[{%22attribute%22:%22level%22,%22value%22:{%22condition%22:%22=%22,%22value%22:4}}]
```

but when i use this url in `fetch()` it doesn't work

```
fetch("https://apiv4.ordering.co/v400/en/devyv4/users&where[{%22attribute%22:%22level%22,%22value%22:{%22condition%22:%22=%22,%22value%22:4}}]", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "x-api-key": ""
            }
        }).then(r =>  r.json().then(data => (alert(JSON.stringify(data.result)))))
```

How i can use this in url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at the URL you're passing. You need to define the start of your search string with `?`

`fetch("https://....co/v400/path?mode=dashboard&params=id,name,lastname&where...")`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `?` after users to start the searchParams, atm you have a `&` not sure if you missed part of the URL or what.